# Cannot Query Parent with Many to Many Association - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 3 models with the following structure:

```
class Customer
     has_many :invoices
     has_and_belongs_to_many :locations
end

class Invoice
    belongs_to :customer
end

class Location
    has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
end
```

I'm trying to write a query that will grab invoices that have parents associated to a specific location but the query I have come up with returns no results.

```
Invoice.where(customer: [locations: {id: specified_location.id}])
```

I'm not sure how to get this to work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to `join` your query with associated models. Also in `where` arguments there should be a Hash instead of Array (looks like a misprint; otherwise it will be a syntax error).

Your call is:

```
Invoice.joins(customer: :locations)
       .where(customer: { locations: { id: specified_location.id } })
```